# Can I create a lookup field that only returns "Current" list items?

Tags: sharepoint, lookup, filtered-lookup, wss-2.0

I'm working with Sharepoint 2.0 (WSS2) and need to create a lookup field that draws the name of an Issue from an Issue List.  The trouble is, it does not appear that I can filter this lookup so that only the current version of the Issue is pulled up.  The result is that I have several selections for the same Issue that appear in the lookup.

I know that there is Add-on software out there to help with this, but my employer will not allow these types of add-ons on the system.

Any suggestions for work arounds that can be done within SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't use 3rd party software consider creating another copy of the list, one for "Active" and another for "All".  Use a SharePoint Designer workflow to copy the list item from All to Active, upon close use another workflow to delete the item.

I understand that you have another list, probably something like IssuesLog that needs to link via lookup to the Issues list.  I'd simply have that the Issues Log link to Issues and IssuesCurrent -> basically have 2 lookup columns.  With creative use of views nobody will ever know the difference.